# rails 3 rails couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap' pt2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

This is my second post regarding this issue as my webrick server spits out this message. I've had this before and twiddled with the application.css file to get it to work. My rails is 3.1.3 on ruby 1.9.3. The response from rails is couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'

"all" %>

Researching on Google I've followed seyhunak's responses on this issue. Here is my line in the Gemfile, on its own line and not in a group.

```
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'http://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

Here is what's in my application.css.scss:

```
  *= require_self
  *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
  *= require_tree .
```

Here's what's in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require twitter/bootstrap
 //= require require_tree .
```

I have done the following commands:

```
 bundle update
 rails g bootstrap:install
 rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed
 touch bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
 rails s
```

After restarting the server, I still get that error. I'm unable to get past this.

I think I've exhausted all Stack and Google can suggest. What am I overlooking? thanx, sam

Comment: Try removing the //= require bootstrap line

Comment: If you mean the application.js file, then it removing it produced the same "file not Found" error. Is it somewhere else? thx.

Comment: Yes I meant in the application.js file. The correct require statement is twitter/bootstrap. May I ask why is the other bootstrap in the list?

Comment: Unsure which other bootstrap you're referring. My application.js has //= require twitter/bootstrap per the question above.

Comment: @sam452 Please check upgrading wiki @github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: Thx. I've done all on that page that applied to rails except @linkcolor. Still no love after restarting webrick. @github.com/sam452/kerikut2 in the bootstrap branch? Perhaps someone could see what I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After beating myself up over this, I got some Rails devs to look at this problem. My understanding is that Twitter/Bootstrap needs files to be in the vendor directory. The gem would then need to be removed, commented out, so they would not conflict. My app now shows pages that look like the project's homepage. I'm unsure if I've lost the ability to use less to change things. This is my inexperience showing. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Moving `twitter-bootstrap-rails` outside assets group can help: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/91

Comment: Thanks for following up. Reading up on @seyhunak's thread, others moved it out of development as well. This likely shows my ignorance but if you cannot develop or deploy with the gem, what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

Moving gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" out of group :assets

And doing a bundle install worked for me.

Here is some more information

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/91

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem,
I use application.html.haml instead of application.html.erb
using this link:
[HTML to Haml](http://html2haml.heroku.com/)

Code is as:

```
%html
  %head
   %title Task
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
%body
 = yield
```

You Must install Haml gem first:
[install haml gem rails](https://github.com/haml/haml)